# Find a solution for broadcast and receive file via wifi?

Tags: android, wifi, broadcast

I'm trying to make an app Android which can :
- Broadcast a file in a local network wifi.
- Receiver the file which is broadcasted by the other mobile.

I don't have much experience. So, I hope that you guys can give me some solutions.

These other question : Which API of Android can solve this problem? The maximum volume of file that I can send?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html.

That allows you to discover devices on wifi with you, then send data to them via normal sockets.

There is a wifi-direct sample app with the SDK.

please use this code to attach file with intent

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File fileDir= new File(sd, "dir_path");
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                                + FILE_TXT
intent.setAction("set_your_Action_here");
sendBroadcast(intent);// broadcast your text file.
```

Comment: Thank for answer my question, but it is not what I want. I want my app broadcast the file in network local, it don't need to make the connection with other mobile. The other mobiles which has been installed my app can receive the file in local.

Comment: @Jgan i added some code for attaching file with broadcasting intent. but according to your requirement you need to use Push Notification feature for notify other users having this app installed to getting your file.

Comment: @IrshadKhan, .... could you help me also?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357892/how-to-solve-discovering-other-device-via-wi-fi-android-api?noredirect=1#comment37663295_24357892